# pandas aggregating frames by largest common column denominator and filling missing values

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, alignment, concatenation

I have been struggling with this issue for a bit and even though there are some workarounds i would assume, I would love to know if there is an elegant way to achieve this result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
            [1,10],
            [2,12],
            [4,13],
            [5,14],
            [8,15]])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=range(0,5), columns=['x','a'])

data = np.array([
            [2,100,101],
            [3,120,122],
            [4,130,132],
            [7,140,142],
            [9,150,151],
            [12,160,152]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=range(0,6), columns=['x','b','c'])
```

Now I would like to have a data frame that concatenate those 2 and fill the missing values with the previous value
or the first value otherwise. Both data frames can have differnet sizes, what we are interested in here is the unique column x.

That would be my desired output frame df_result.
x is the aggregated unique "x" between the 2 frames

```
    x   a   b   c
0   1   10  100 101
1   2   12  100 101
2   3   12  120 122
3   4   13  130 132
4   5   14  130 132
5   7   14  140 142
6   8   15  140 142
7   9   15  150 151
8   12  15  160 152
```

Any help or hint would be much appreciated, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use merge operation on 2 dataframes, after that you can apply a sorting, forward fill and backward filling for null values fillling.

```
df1.merge(df2,on='x',how='outer').sort_values('x').ffill().bfill()
```

Out:

```
   x     a       b       c
0   1   10.0    100.0   101.0
1   2   12.0    100.0   101.0
5   3   12.0    120.0   122.0
2   4   13.0    130.0   132.0
3   5   14.0    130.0   132.0
6   7   14.0    140.0   142.0
4   8   15.0    140.0   142.0
7   9   15.0    150.0   151.0
8   12  15.0    160.0   152.0
```